# eclipse jar export wizard hangs

Tags: eclipse, jar

Eclipse jar export wizard hangs for more than an hour ,how to kill or close only wizard instead of whole eclipse.Something  how to find eclipse dialog box process id in windows Task Manager.

[image: Error Page Screen Shot]
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I very much doubt Eclipse starts a new process fo the wizard. You'll have to kill Eclipse.

Comment: So no other go ? Thanks for reply.